# Как учить синтаксис C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Пытаюсь учить C#, но это оказывается неожиданно сложно сделать.
Я прочитал несколько книжек по нему и все равно выходит, что я не понимаю и половину синтаксиса.
Складывается впечатление, что в C# вводят новый синтаксис быстрее, чем я успеваю учить.
В связи с этим вопрос: есть ли какое-то место, жирная книжка или что-то еще, где описан весь синтаксический сахар си шарпа. Куда можно было бы упороться, но после изучения материала более-менее свободно читать чужой код.

Comment: Я упарываюсь в гугл, проблем не испытываю. Ну или [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) например. Знание синтаксиса не единственное, что нужно знать, чтобы читать чужой код. Надо знать еще шаблоны проектирования (паттерны) и ООП, а так же всё про многопоточность и асинхронность.

Comment: Смотри на github чужой код, отлаживай по строчке и разбирай что происходит

Comment: Синтаксис и синт. сахар - две разные вещи, где первый, это как положено писать код (`тип Название(типАргумента названиеАргумента) { код }`), а второй, это различные улучшения, позволяющие этот код сократить и сделать более читаемым и приятном для глаза программиста, например из нового, раньше: `if (person != null && person.Name == "Вася" && person.Age == 18){ .. }`, сейчас: `if (person as {Name: "Вася", Age: 18}){ .. }` и то и то делает, по сути, одно и тоже, но что приятней и удобней? А книги, мое ИМХО, начните писать свой проект (лучше публичный и для кого-то) и там оттачивайте свой навык.

Comment: Просто сядьте и напишите что нибудь простое. Например, консольные крестики - нолики. Только так можно упороться в синтаксис. Книги можно использовать как справочник.

Comment: Если вы прочитали книгу по C#, то должны понимать основы. Далее, посмотрите историю изменений языка C#, начиная с C# 5.0. Так будет проще всего понять новые возможности языка.

Comment: [Вот полезная ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history) по истории C# с официальной документации Microsoft. Там слева есть навигация по истории версий с C# 6.0.

Comment: [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/)
[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/)
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

Есть разные тренажёры кода типа https://itvdn.com/ru/skills или https://www.sololearn.com/Play/CSharp . Но лучший тренажер, это много кодить